# Angular Breadcrumb for lazy loaded modules, if one module has another module displayed within its tab

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, breadcrumbs, xng-breadcrumb

The project has lazy loaded modules. If I switch from one module to another, I want the breadcrumb to be stored for both the modules.
I have used xng-breadcrumb, but it does not persist the route of previous routing module and starts the new routes module.
There are 2 routing modules, Employee and Project.
These are two independent tabs. But also, there could be the projects that will be created at the time I add a new employee. Hence this independent tab Project can also be added from Employee tab page. There is no parent child relation they are saved on the basis of ids.

So, when I go from Home to employee tab the breadcrumb is Home > Employee.
If the Employee page has a new tab for Projects(different module), when I click on Projects, I need the breadcrumb as **Home > Employee > Projects > Project Name.**
Rather it gets displayed as **Home > Projects > Project Name.**

Can anyone help me achieve this scenario. If I can achieve this using xng-breadcrumb, it would be great. Otherwise, any solution would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful for you to share all relevant code - but no more. It is generally a good idea to share a live demo using a site like stackblitz as well in situations where you have different states to visualise.